# Is it possible to have mulitple inboxes in Thunderbird as in GMail?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, sorting, inbox

I would like to have a feature similar to what I currently use in GMail:

- one inbox with all unread email;
- one inbox with all starred email;
- one inbox with everything else.

Note that all these inboxes are visible at the same time, all three of them are just "Inbox".

It's useful as I have direct access to my newly received emails, which I can then read and potentially star as a reminder for later, and can also see my starred emails.

In Thunderbird I've only been able to have one inbox, which can be sorted in whichever way, but not in the exact manner I'd like (it is possible to sort by starred, which then puts all starred messages first, and then the other messages by date, which is close to what I want but not the same).

Is it possible to have multiple inboxes like this in Thunderbird?

EDIT: This is what Gmail multiple inboxes look like:

[image]

So just creating a folder with starred messages in Thunderbird is not what I'm looking for, unless I can have that folder visible with the main inbox like above.

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for virtual folders, this exists and is called "saved search" in Thunderbird.

At the moment I cannot test and verify if it (still) works, but [here](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Saved_Search#Creating_a_Saved_Search_folder) are the instructions for how to create a virtual folder based on a "saved search":

1. In Thunderbird go to the `Edit` menu and choose `Find -> Search Messages`.
2. (Alternatively, get a context menu for a folder, for example by right-clicking it, and choose: `Search...`)
3. enter your search criteria
4. click the <kbd>Search</kbd> button
5. you can then save your search by clicking the <kbd>Save as Search Folder</kbd> button

[image: screenshot]

further reading:

- https://kb.mozillazine.org/Search_-_Thunderbird#Saved_Search
- https://kb.mozillazine.org/Folders_and_views
- https://kb.mozillazine.org/Saved_Search#Creating_a_Saved_Search_folder

Comment: Why the downvote? Please tell me how to improve the answer, which is IMO correct.